# linux mintでEmacsが起動しない

Tags: linux, emacs

Emacsをインストールしましたが、Emacsを開けません。

以下サイトを参考にEmacsをダウンロードしました。
http://baker-street.jugem.jp/?eid=636

Answer (score 3):

参考にされたページの手順ではパッケージ名に`emacs-nox`を指定していますが、[リポジトリ](https://launchpad.net/~kelleyk/+archive/ubuntu/emacs/+packages)を確認すると(コンソール版の)正しいパッケージ名は`emacs25-nox`または`emacs26-nox`のようです。
起動しない原因は**そもそもインストールが完了していない**可能性があるので、例えば`which emacs`などを実行してインストールが出来ているかを確認してください。

何かパッケージをインストールする場合には、事前に`apt search`で正しいパッケージ名の確認やパッケージが存在するかを確認したほうが確実です。今回の場合なら追加のPPA(リポジトリ)を指定せずとも公式リポジトリに`emacs`および`emacs-nox`が存在しました。

私が試した環境は少し古いLinux Mint 17.3ですが、

```
$ sudo apt seach emacs
```

一覧から`emacs23-nox`または`emacs24-nox`がコンソール版のパッケージ名だとわかります。この後

```
$ sudo apt install emacs24-nox
```

を実行すれば目的のパッケージがインストールされ、コンソールから`emacs`で起動までを確認できました。
(バージョン番号等は実行環境によって変わりますので、実際の環境で確認のうえ読み替えてください)

---

なお、質問の際は「インストール」や「コマンドの起動」をした際に何かしらのメッセージが表示されるはずなので、そのメッセージを質問文に含めてもらった方が回答が付きやすいと思います。

Comment: 解決しましたありがとうございます